# "The handle is invalid" execption recevied while creating the object of MQ Queue Manager

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Please find the below code:

```
MQEnvironment.Hostname = HostName;
        MQEnvironment.Channel = Channel;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SSLKeyRepository))
        {
            MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = SSLCipherSpec;
            MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = SSLKeyRepository;
        }
        if (Port > 0)
            MQEnvironment.Port = Port;

        try
        {
            MQManager = new MQQueueManager(QueueManager);
            try
            {
                MQRequestQueue = MQManager.AccessQueue(QueueNameGet, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
                MQResponseQueue = MQManager.AccessQueue(QueueNameGet, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);                     
                return true;
            }
            catch (IBM.WMQ.MQException exIBM)
            {
                CloseConnection();
                ErrorCode = exIBM.Reason;
                ErrorDescription = exIBM.Message;
                                }
        }
        catch (IBM.WMQ.MQException exIBM)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            ErrorCode = exIBM.Reason;
            ErrorDescription = exIBM.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CloseConnection();
            ErrorCode = Constants.SYSTEMEXCEPTION;
            ErrorDescription = ex.Message;
        }
        return false;
```

Issue: I am not getting the issue when I run it for single or 2-3 times. But I get the issue when it runs in a loop for multiple times.
Also, I have tried to run the same piece of code for 10,000 times from the IIS server and it ran successfully.

I am getting the issue only when I have this code on IIS webservice and that webservice is getting called multiple times.

IBM MQ client 7.5.0.0 installed on the IIS server and I am using the dll of the same version.

**UPDATE**
Error description:

Error Message  The handle is invalid
    StackTrace     at     System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)     at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()     at IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceEnvironment()     at IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.CreateCommonServices()     at IBM.WMQ.CommonServices.TraceEnabled()     at IBM.WMQ.MQBase..ctor()     at IBM.WMQ.MQManagedObject..ctor()

Comment: Can you post the exact exception stack? Does your application opens a connection to queue manager every time it put/gets message? Are you closing queue(s) that you have opened by calling close method and connections by calling disconnect method on queue manager object?

Comment: yes, it opens the connection every time while get/put the message. and yes I close the queues and queue manager every time after finishing get/put. So code is written like this
1. open queue manager
2. access queue
3. get/put the message on Queue
4.disconnect and close the QM
5.disconnect queues

Comment: I don't have the exact exception stack

Comment: @Shashi, looking at profile it seems you are having the more idea on how to work with MQseries component available for .NET. as Roger mentioned below MQEnvironment class is not thread safe, isn't it??

Comment: MQEnvironment class has a static constructor. Hence it get initialized only once per application. All threads in an application will use the one and only one instance of the MQEnvironment class. More diagnostic information is needed to understand what the "the handle is invalid" error means.

Comment: @Shashi, I have updated the error description. hope it will be helpful to you get the idea what error means

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the call stack. The issue you mention is very similar to the one fixed [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC90674) in MQ version 7.5.0.2. As you are at MQ v7.5.0.0, I suggest you to upgrade your MQ client to the latest level, MQ v7.5.0.7 and try.

Comment: it seems your answer is nearer to the problem I caught. will update you with new logs if I find any

Answer (score 0):

I have said this many times here and it applies to both Java and .NET, the MQEnvironment class is NOT thread safe.  By using it, you are shooting yourself in the foot.

Put the values (channel, hostname & port #) into a HashTable and pass the HashTable to the MQQueueManager class.

```
Hashtable qMgrHT = new Hashtable();
qMgrHT.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

qMgrHT.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "10.10.10.10");
qMgrHT.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "TEST.CHL");
qMgrHT.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);

qMgrHT.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "myUserID");
qMgrHT.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "myPwd");

MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, qMgrHT);
```

Finally, write your code so that it maintains a connection rather than connecting and disconnecting over and over.  Very, VERY bad form.

Comment: Hey Roger, thanks for replying it. But,I am not passing any of the parameter rather than the QM name.

 I am just surprised if MQEnvironment variables can be passed in the QM as parameter like you did(I am new to MQseries)

Also, This particular code I've placed in the service which is hosted on my IIS server so that available to everyone. how can I maintain the connection. I thought its good to connect/disconnect the after using it.

Comment: ,you mean to say the way I have written the code is very bad format?
you can find the  steps I have written in my above comment to Shashi